# Error :Not storing ID in DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

actually I am storing the three Values in Data Base,it successfully storing date, path but not storing the gallery id, here is my code I am using

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();
include("include/conf.php");
$getid=$_GET['id_cms'];
$galleryid=$_GET['gallery'];
$date=date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root
$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);


if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
//$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
//move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,"gallery/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$path=$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

mysql_query("Insert into gallery (gall_date,albumid,gallery_path) VALUES('$date','$galleryid','$path')",$cn) or die("Insert Query Error");

}} ?>
```

I have already spent two days on it but all in Vain.

Could any body please solve my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Edit: incorrect advice.

Comment: Does `ID` fiield have the default auto increment?

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions..

Comment: Is the ID given in the URL ? Or is it empty in the URL as well ?

Comment: @Will No, that is not true. leave the apostrophes, even if it is an int.

Comment: By the way, please make use of mysql_real_escape_string() function, because you have SQL injection possible!

Comment: actually I have two pages where in first page I load the gallery (title image of gallery) and getting the same id in the next page and uploading the album across this gallery id.

Comment: I don't see where you define `$cn`? What is in your logs?

Comment: yes nl-x id can be view in browser and it is also view if we print the id,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try with

```
$getid=$_POST['id_cms'];
$galleryid=$_POST['gallery'];
```

instead of

```
$getid=$_GET['id_cms'];
$galleryid=$_GET['gallery'];
```

You are using post method so you should  use $_POST  but you are trying to access using $_GET.

Also try with

```
$_REQUEST['gallery']
```

add below line in ur javascript

```
'gallery' : '<?php echo $_REQUEST['gallery'];?>'
```

Comment: it is not even inserting get, post values in Database

Comment: actually I have two pages where in first page I load the gallery (title image of gallery) and getting the same id in the next page and uploading the album across this gallery id.

Comment: you can take the sql query after submission n check directly in query browser like phpmyadmin..also make sure you have added the name attribute in the text boxes for id_cms,gallery.can u show the form here...

Comment: which kind of form, do u need snap shot of the page,

Comment: when we create album in first page and go to the second page to create the gallery of the album its id can be view in browser,mean id is picked in browser but not storing in database.

Comment: how can I send you my files (piece of code + html form) of whole page?santanu kumar

Comment: send ur form only or make a snap...also try using $_REQUEST INSTEAD OF $_GET to see if u catch the values

Comment: $_REQUEST INSTEAD OF $_GET is not working, it is inserting all the stuff e.g images, title , but not the values of post and get ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30405/discussion-between-santanu-kumar-and-saeed-khan)

Comment: you are welcome n next time be sure to explain in details else it will  be lengthy..

Answer (score 0):

if `$_GET['gallery']` contains some value it must be updated in the database.
You have to check the below things

- Is gallery item posted received through GET, print the `$_REQUEST` to see if it's coming through your request
- If it's proper, then check the DB, that albumid is set a proper data type i.e integer data type in your case

If it's still not resolved kindly check any error thrown in the log.